# Unable to post data in .json file

Tags: arrays, angularjs, json, ionic-framework

I am trying to create a hybrid application using ionic framework but I am stuck at one point. All I trying to do is save values from three different input boxes into  'data.json' file and retrieve that data or make change whenever needed and values should remain there regardless of whether application is running or not.

```
$http.get('js/data.json').success(function (data) {
    $scope.values = data;
});
```

html

```
<div ng-repeat="yoyo in values">
    <p ><h2>{{yoyo.name}}</h2></p>
</div>`
```

Using this bit of code I'm able to loop through the objects available in array in data.json file. But I am unable to post anything into it.

```
$scope.process = function () {
   // var SendData = angular.toJson({
     // json: JSON.stringify( ) });

var SendData= {
  "name": $scope.box1,
    "owners": $scope.box2,
  "country": $scope.box3,
};

$http.post('js/data.json',SendData)
    .success(function () { 
        console.log('done it bro'); 
    });
};
```

However above function triggered whenever button is clicked. It should take values from those three boxes and should push into data.json file but nothing happens. I cannot see any change in **{{yoyo.name}}** as this should show me all the objects in array. However I can see my .success function it executed in `console.log`

Please advise why cant i save data in .json file or what is right way to do it?

Comment: Is your file read-only by any chance?

Comment: @PmanAce by going to properties  of data.json file I can see read-only radio button is not  checked  hence I guess its not  read only?   Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot save a file in server using vanilla JavaScript. Think of all the problems that occur if a malicious user can post data to our server using just his JavaScript console? That is why its not allowed.

So we use AJAX, a tool to communicate with another server-side API endpoint that actually does the job for us. Here you can use `localStorage` to save your `SendData`. A better approach will be using a service or factory like this.

```
app.factory("LocalStorageService", ["$window", function ($window) {
    var HasKey = function (key) {
        return $window.localStorage && $window.localStorage.getItem(key);
    };
    var GetItem = function (key) {
        if ($window.localStorage) {
            return $window.localStorage.getItem(key);
        }
        return null;
    };
    var SetItem = function (key, value) {
        if ($window.localStorage) {
            $window.localStorage.setItem(key, value);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    };
    var RemoveItem = function (key) {
        if ($window.localStorage) {
            return $window.localStorage.removeItem(key);
        }
        return null;
    };
    return {
        HasKey: HasKey,
        GetItem: GetItem,
        SetItem: SetItem,
        RemoveItem: RemoveItem
    };
}]);
```

Now to insert into `localStorage`, inject the factory into your app and call it like,

```
//To store into localStorage
LocalStorageService.SetItem("personalDetails", JSON.stringify(SendData));

//To retrieve from localStorage
var DTO = LocalStorageService.GetItem("personalDetails");
var personalDetails = JSON.parse(DTO);
```

P.S: Please start using better naming conventions soon. Or else it will become a bad habit not that easy to break. ;)

Comment: Thanks mate,  I looked at above example and I understand the concept of it. Just a question how would I add new elements in "personalDetails" and keep updating it. I dont want to have multiple keys for multiple values. I all data to be stored under one key in jSon format. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

To do `$http.post` you need a back end API(PHP,Node Js etc) that catch your desired  data and save into the db or JSON by Read-write method in file system.

Comment: Can't  I simply store file in local  storage ?  I don't  want to store data in server. What is the right way to do this?

Comment: Also, if it can http.get data from json file it should also be able to write it?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write the data directly into the .j son file. but you can receive the data from the .j son file. for such scenarios you can go the option such as browser local storage,web SQL,SQL lite.

Remember for the static .j son file in the local can have only used for read j son value.

Comment: I will try localstorage coz thats what I need.  I tried storing data in one function  but this data disappears when page is reloaded...  but i need opposite  to it. Cheers  anyway

Comment: From your code snippet. I can able to understand your fetching the data from data.json file in your local and in success your try to right to same data.json. which is not possible.. if you updated snippet please share it here.. if you using local storage thn you have reassign the local storage value on all dom refresh... sorry if any thing of my view goes wrong.